# Fact regarding Kirchhoff's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Question regarding **Kirchhoff's Theorem**:

> If $ L(G)$ denotes the Laplacian of a graph $G$ then **Kirchhoff's Theorem** states that number of spanning trees in $G$ is equal to $(-1)^{i+j} \det L(i|j)$ where $L(i|j)$ is obtained by deleting the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column.

But how does that give that **number of spanning trees is equal to $\frac{1}{n}\{\lambda_1 \lambda_2...\lambda_{n-1}\}$ where $\lambda_i$ are non-zero eigen values of $L(G)$**.

Please help me to understand the second result stated in bold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to obtain this result from Kirchhoffs Theorem is the following (following "Biggs, *Algebraic graph theory*"):

**Step 1 (Temperley 1964)** For a graph $X$ with $n$ vertices and its Laplacian $L=L(X)$ it holds that
$$ \tau(X) = n^{-2} \text{det}(J + L),$$
where $J$ is the matrix with all entries equal to $1$ and $\tau(X)$ is the number of spanning trees.

*Proof*: By the following two formulas $nJ = J^2$ and $LJ = JL = \textbf{0}$ we easily obtain
$$(nI - J)(J+L)=nL.$$
Taking adjugates on both sides one gets
$$\text{adj}(nI-J) \text{adj}(J+L) = \text{adj}(nL).$$
Now one uses that $nI-J = L(K_n)$, i.e. the Laplacian of the complete graph, hence $\text{adj}(nI-J)$ equals $n^{n-2}J$. Moreover using $\text{adj}(nL) = n^{n-1}\text{adj}(L)$ one obtains
$$\text{adj}(J+L) J= n \tau(X) J.$$
Multiplying this equation by $(J + L)$ finally gives the result.

**Step 2**: $\tau(X) = n^{-1} \prod \lambda_i$ where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{n-1}$ are the non-zero eigenvalues of $L$.

*Proof*: $J$ and $L$, as it was used above commute. Hence they are simultaneously diagonalizable. Hence the eigenvalues of $J+L$ are just the sum of the corresponding eigenvalues of $J$ and $L$. As the eigenvalues of $J$ are $n, 0, 0, \dots, 0$ the eigenvalues of $J+L$ are $n, \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{n-1}$. Now since the determinant equals the product of eigenvalues, Step 1 settles the proof.

Comment: Thanks ,can you please suggest some books on this subject if you have studied before

Comment: I have just started reading this topic

Comment: I would recommend "Biggs: *Algebraic graph theory*" (which is kind of "classical") and in any case you must (in my opinion) read "Godsil, Royle: *Algebraic graph theory*"

Comment: Well just for curiosity what's your take on this topic ?What are the various possibilities of research available here?

Comment: Have you just read /have undergone some research in this field here

Comment: I personally started working with this topic for my bachelor thesis. However right now I'm only concerned with one little research question in this area. In any case there is much research done, in particular concerning the Laplacian matrix of a (weighted) graph. Moreover also applied mathematicians are concerned with studying the Laplacian (but I'm not an expert on this). For example look for "spectral sparsification of graphs" to get a feeling for how beautiful and deep mathematics in this area can be. In particular Dan Spielman has to be named (as of course many others) in this context.

Comment: Thank you very much ;that was so nice of you

Answer (score 3):

Your answer can be found at

https://saadquader.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/kirchhoffs-matrix-tree-theorem-for-counting-spanning-trees-proof/

or at:

www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/264A-LECTUREJ.pdf