# What is the adjugate matrix of the laplacian of a complete graph $K_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

In [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665210/fact-regarding-kirchhoffs-theorem/1665334), I'm trying to understand the author's logic in a certain line of the accepted answer.

"Now one uses that $nI-J=L(K_n)$, i.e. the Laplacian of the complete graph, hence $\text{adj}(nI-J)$ equals $n^{n-2}J$." Also, $J$ is a matrix entirely filled with ones.

From observation, it seems that the determinant of $L(K_n)$ is $0$, so one could use the previously established fact that $JL=LJ=0$, where $L$ is any Laplacian matrix, and show that $\text{adj}(L(K_n))=J$. The factor of $n^{n-2}$ is arbitrary and is included out of convenience for the rest of the proof.

However, if this is the case how would one show that $\text{det}(L(K_n))=0$?

Comment: Do you mean $L(K_n)$ in your last line? If so, then its determinant is $0$ because you have exhibited an eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$ (the all-ones vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result comes from [the matrix tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) which says that the number of spanning trees of the graph is given by any cofactor of the Laplacian, so that the adjugate is $tJ$ where $t$ is the number of spanning trees.  The fact that $t=n^{n-2}$ in this case follows from a theorem of Caley, which is proved in the linked Wikipedia article.

The Laplacian of any graph is singular, since the row sums are all $0$.